# Android:Java Unable to find class at runtime from JAR I created

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jar

I am working through a facebook-sdk example and trying to utilize the collection of classes as provided as a .JAR.  I am relatively new to java and eclipse so I expect I am making some obvious blunder.

The issue is that everything seems to compile fine, but when I run the project (using the android emulator) dalvik vm is unable to find the first class I reference from this facebook sdk.  ( com/facebook/android/Facebook.class )

As an aside, if I copy the source directly into my project as an additional package everything works fine.

Step 1: I exported the com_facebook_android project as a .JAR file. ( right click project, export, java / jar file ) I choose c:\data\jag\jar as my location to save facebooksdk.jar.

Step 2: I hit properties on the project HelloGoogleMaps, Selected Java Build Path, Libraries, Add External JARS...  I the directly selected the c:\data\jag\jar\facebooksdk.jar file.

At this point my project seems to be building just fine ( no errors ).
[image]

Step 3: Debug the project and receive the error:

[2010-11-19 09:05:08 - Example] ActivityManager: Error: Activity class {com.facebook.android/com.facebook.android.Example} does not exist.
[2010-11-19 09:05:11 - Example] Starting activity com.facebook.android.Example on device 
[2010-11-19 09:05:12 - Example] New package not yet registered with the system. Waiting 3 seconds before next attempt.

[2010-11-19 09:05:15 - Example] Starting activity com.facebook.android.Example on device

[2010-11-19 09:05:17 - Example] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.facebook.android/.Example }

[2010-11-19 09:05:17 - Example] New package not yet registered with the system. Waiting 3 seconds before next attempt.

[2010-11-19 09:05:20 - Example] Starting activity com.facebook.android.Example on device

[2010-11-19 09:05:21 - Example] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.facebook.android/.Example }

[2010-11-19 09:05:21 - Example] ActivityManager: Error type 3

[2010-11-19 09:05:21 - Example] ActivityManager: Error: Activity class {com.facebook.android/com.facebook.android.Example} does not exist.

SHAWN -- Here are the Android properties for my project.

[image]

Comment: Where is the Example class defined?  And where is it being used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you set the Java Build Path, you only did that: set the build path itself. This caused you to get a successful compile. However, when the .apk file is created, the system does not know that you need external jar files to be bundled along with your source files.

I have not done this before, but it looks like if you right click on your com_facebook_android project and select Properties > Android, you should select the Is Library box. Then go into the Android properties of your main project and click Add... and choose the external library. I believe this will do what you need.

EDIT:
This is called a Library Project, and is a fairly new addition to the SDK. You can find more information at http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/eclipse-adt.html#libraryProject

Comment: Hi Shawn.. argh, feels like you handed me the keys to the kingdom and I can't find the key hole.  The dialog (properties, android) doesn't appear to have a "Is Library" dialog.  Wouldn't it seem that I need to tell the including project (helloGoogleMaps) not the included (facebookSdk) that it should bundle the JAR?

Comment: Yes, you tell the including project that it should bundle the JAR. However it only gives you the choice of projects that are declared as a Library.

Comment: When I view the Android properties, it has two sections; the first is Project Build Target and the second is Library; it's this second section that contains the Is Library checkbox.

Comment: Were you able to figure it out?

Comment: Hi Shawn - I copied my properties dialog to the initial question at the bottom ( can't put a picture in comments ).  I still don't see a way to make it a library.  I did solve the problem in a manner of speaking. I added a .jar file and then selected the .apk file from the bin directory of the com_facebook_android project.  That in conjunction with the build path seems to have things working.  I am convinced I am doing it "the hard way" and would be interested in resolving your approach.

Comment: Ok, my Eclipse installation looks different; I suspect you have an old version of the SDK installed. I also found more information on this: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/eclipse-adt.html#libraryProject. I'll edit my answer with this link.

Comment: BTW, you can update your plugin by following the instructions at http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#updating

Comment: hah, good timing Shawn, just popped in.  I am upgrading.. I think your reference, covers it completely. I appreciate all of your help on this.  I wouldn't have guessed the solution was to upgrade my eclipse / adt version.  Best Regards!

Comment: Glad I could help -- thanks for marking the solution complete!

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to add com.facebook.android as a library into your project...
if i am not wrong this is android facebook sdk.
  You can check this link out...
See the instructions over here:

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk

Hope it helps you........
Thanksss

Comment: viv - I am working with what you are referring to. the problem I am having is getting my project to include/bundle the .JAR file that I created from that facebookSDK.

Comment: this is the same one as i have used, that's why i am saying to follow the instruction's given on the link, i also tried making the jar, but that didn't help me......     at least u should give it a try, rest is all on you, luck and god,  thanks.................. god bless you

Comment: viv - agreed. I really have tried to follow the instructions on that page and I must be misreading because i end up with the same results.  One of the steps on that site is to build an "Example" project and include the facebookSDK.  I have done that as well and have the same problems as described.  I posted above what I ended up doing to get around this, but it feels poorly implemented.   best regards

Answer (score 0):

ok, really not comfortable about what I did to get me past this.
1) I added the .jar as an external jar.
2) I then also included the .apk file as a .jar (not external jar)  I had to select this directly from com_facebook_android/bin/com_facebook_android.apk.

it seems like I am solving this with brute force and something else would be more appropriate.